# Duplicate key in wcf webservice config

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, configuration

I have this configuration in a WCF webservice:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="200000" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://webserver/myService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService" name="IService" />
        <endpoint address="http://webserver/myService1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Documents.IDocService" name="Documents.IDocService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"  />
    </protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am getting the following warning in a trace file (diagnostics svclog).

> The configuration system has detected a duplicate key in a different
>   configuration scope and is overriding with the more recent value.

and it points the following line:

```
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"  />
    </protocolMapping>
```

I don't see what could be duplicated. Could you give me a hint what the issue is?

Comment: Is there a config file at a higher level that may be setting this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a clear, then you remove duplicates:

```
<protocolMapping>
   <clear/>
   <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"  />
</protocolMapping>
```

like this.

Answer (score 3):

This happen because you have another configuration section defining behavior for this protocol mapping. Using `<clear/>` tag inside protocol mapping will remove the first config. This apply to all the same conflict, also appear in connection string among others. When you are calling one service as from another app, the upper level of config could overwrite some behavior in the second one...

Comment: Yes that is my exact same thought, but could you point it in the configuration I have shared?

Comment: could you tell us where you are calling the service?

Comment: this is the configuration of the web service, I am calling the service from a client application

Comment: could you post the client application config or check for this duplication in this config. When you are calling one service from another app, the upper level of config could overwrite some behavior in the second one...

Comment: that is true, it is possible that an existing web.config is overwriting